# Ubuntu 16.04.2: CUPS can't print to Windows SMB share

Tags: networking, windows, printing, samba

after a few years of flawless printing to our campus' printserver via Windows SMB shares, I now get the following error in /var/log/cups/err_log:

```
    E [15/May/2017:19:35:39 +0200] [Job 701] Connection failed: NT_STATUS_CONNECTION_RESET
    E [15/May/2017:19:35:39 +0200] [Job 701] Connection failed: NT_STATUS_CONNECTION_RESET
    E [15/May/2017:19:35:39 +0200] [Job 701] Connection failed: NT_STATUS_CONNECTION_RESET
    E [15/May/2017:19:35:39 +0200] [Job 701] Connection failed: NT_STATUS_CONNECTION_RESET
    E [15/May/2017:19:35:39 +0200] [Job 701] Unable to connect to CIFS host, will retry in 60 seconds...
```

Needless to say, the print job never reaches the printer. I contacted IT services and they were clearly unwilling to help, given their narrow Windoze mindset.

Any way I can troubleshoot this? Apparently it's not an authentication issue, as no connection even gets established (but correct me if I'm wrong). Any help appreciated before I bring my own printer to work. ;^)

--GT

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My guess is that they disabled SMB1 support on the printserver after the WannaCry outbreak. Ubuntu defaults to SMB1 when printing via SAMBA.

We solved it by changing the way the client connects to our servers by forcing SMB2 or higher.

To fix this, change the smb.conf (make a copy first!)

In terminal, after you've made a copy, type:

`sudo gedit /etc/samba/smb.conf`
*(Feel free to use nano or similar instead of gedit if you want).*

In the file, add the following below `[global]`

`client min protocol = SMB2`

`client max protocol = SMB3`

Restart your computer, and check localhost:631 in a browser to verify that it worked.

Sincerely

Torbjørn

PS: The IT-services at our Campus Rocks! 
(I might be biased since I am the IT-services ^^)

Comment: WOW! You, Sir, have just illuminated us all! Much appreciated! Now why didn't that dweeb in IT services I contacted point that out even after I explicitly asked if they changed the protocol?

Comment: Btw, Torbjørn, can we hire you to replace the entire army of useless Windoze-brainwashed IT staff on our campus? ;^) MANY thanks again!

Comment: This worked for me as well, in the same scenario. A minor note: `sudo service cups restart` was sufficient, no need to reboot.

Comment: Still a valid solution! Thanks a lot!